# What call should I make for updating a value in SQLite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

I want to update a value in a specific column in a specific row in my SQLite database. What type of SQLite call should I make? Can I use **rawQuery()** to do this or should I use the **update()** method. What would the call be for these?

The one I have right now is this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("c_uploaded", "true");
String where =  new String("WHERE c_created_at = ?");
String[] created = new String[] {"Tuesday"};
db.update("TABLE", values, where , created);
```

So I want to update the **c_uploaded** column to **true** where the **c_created** column is **tuesday**

Does this make sense or is there a better what to do this?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Use [ORMAN  framework](https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman), it is very easy with that. You just change fields and then say `yourObject.update()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) is the documentation for SQLiteDatabase, and [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) is a good tutorial on how to use it.

As far as the answer to which method you should use, its up to you. If you have a simple update then .rawQuery() may be easiest. If there are a lot of values, then .update() would probably be easier.